# Can ModemManager be used with tethered cell phones or just with dongles?

Tags: modem, tethering

I haven't tried ModemManager yet, but it seems to me that it won't work with a phone plugged into the laptop, unless there is some software running on the phone that acts as a middle-man between ModemManager and the phone's modem.

Answer (score 0):

If the phone is plugged in a laptop it may happen that it already exposes an "already connected" eth over usb (and therefore ModemManager won't be used) or instead an AT-capable serial port (which ModemManager can use to get a connection).